# Cannot create database that is sql sever 2008 is not installed and cannot download that for vs 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I had installed visual studio 2008 but can not create database because sql server express is not installed, and cannot install sql server 2008, and also cannot find proper download from net, all the link where I found the option to download it cannot be downloaded completely,but if I download other things it can be downloaded,so I cannot find a correct download link from where I can download sql server 2008 express completely or what is the problem with my visual studio 2008 ?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/

Select your OS from the right (32bit or 64bit) and you will go to a download page.

Answer (score 0):

And here I cannot download completely sql express 2008 and my download stops when I download sql server 2008 express and does not continue, what should I can not understand because when I download other things it can be , but if I download sql server I cannot and it stops and can not continue, while other downloads can be completed in just few minutes.